# How Spring batch JdbcCursorItemReader read data from database?

Tags: postgresql, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch, and reading data from `postgreSQL` using `JdbcCursorItemReader`. My concern is how internally `JdbcCursorItemReader` reads database records?
For example, if there are 1000k records in database, and chunk size is 1000. So in this case `JdbcCursorItemReader` will try to fetch all 1000k records in JVM and then start execution of 1000 size chunk, or it will fetch only 1000 records from database at a time(or some other way to fetch records).
Also what is the use of `setFetchSize`, and how it is different from mentioning chunk size? 
My requirement is to stream data from `postgreSQL` db to jvm. What configurations do I need for this?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the `JdbcCursorItemReader` is to stream the data from the RDBMS server to the batch job.  This may require some additional configuration based on your setup (I know MySql requires certain parameters...not 100% sure about Postgres).  But the end result when configured correctly is that the data is coming over as needed instead of all at once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to know about the configuration related to PostgreSQL for streaming

Comment: @MichaelMinella Since we are not getting the data all at once, how u guys maintain a pointer on the next field to retrieve? or restarts from that point only if the batch fails?

Comment: Count the number of items read.  You'll need to maintain that the query returns the same data set across runs (there are ways to handle that like the item processed flag, etc).

Comment: I have just setup fetchSize equal to chunk size, and data is getting fetched properly. Though still don't know, how it is managing pointers to next records.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm trying to stream 200M records, and the cursor reader is taking a very long time to start.

Comment: I have confirmed it is trying to read all rows into the resultSet first, and then iterating over each row and sending it to the processor and writer. I am looking for a way to stream the rows it has without waiting for all rows to be fetched.